# Where can find Sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want look for my database in my mobile (HTC M7)

Actually when I use sony mobile I can find it

But now I can't find it since I change HTC M7

This is my data path set up

And where can find it in HTC M7 ?

```
import static android.provider.BaseColumns._ID;
import java.io.File;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Environment;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static Context context;   
       public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Gsensor";  //sqlite table name
       public static final String X = "X";
       public static final String Y = "Y";
       public static final String Z = "Z";
       private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "Gsensor.db";  //database name
       private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  //db ver
       private File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                            File.separator); //db path
       String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                            File.separator + "Gsensor.db";
       private File f = new File(filepath);

       //DB table
       String CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                            X + " CHAR, " + Y + " CHAR, " + Z + " CHAR);";
       //del table
       String DelTable = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
       public DBHelper(Context context) {
           super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
           this.context = context;//openOrCreateDatabase is this method
                                  //so need to init context and return to
      }

       @Override
       //create table
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        SQLiteDatabase dbwrite= context.openOrCreateDatabase("f", context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
        db.execSQL(CreateTable);
      }
       @Override
       //del table
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
         db.execSQL(DelTable);
         onCreate(db);

      }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't `Gsensor.db` in the default `/data/data/your.app.name/databses/` path?

Comment: @DerGolem  this preset path , If I want find it in this path My mobile need root , but I don't want to root .

Comment: And so your users are able to delete it when they want. Nice.

Comment: @DerGolem I just want to cheak my DB info is right or yet.

Comment: You should consider your users like screaming monkeys. More often than not, they don't know what they are doing. So if you leave your db on the sd card, they are free to dismantle it. And your app could stop working in the expected way. Do your experiments **in the emulator**.

Comment: @DerGolem oh ! Yes ! I can use emulator to cheak ! I forget this way ! thx for ur help

Comment: Using the emulator is a healthy habit, since it is surely slower than a real device. So, if the app runs decently in the emulator, it will run far better on a real device.

Comment: @DerGolem I will remember your advice,I learn much from you

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy databases to a public folder if you do not have root privileges. You can copy a database just like a regular file and you may find these functions useful. Use it like that

```
copyFileOrDirectory(getDatabasePath(),
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
 + File.separator + "Gsensor" + File.separator + "Gsensor.db");

public static String getDatabasePath() {
    return (Environment.getDataDirectory() + File.separator + "Gsensor.db");
}

public static void copyFileOrDirectory(String srcDir, String dstDir) {

    try {
        File src = new File(srcDir);
        File dst = new File(dstDir, src.getName());

        if (src.isDirectory()) {

            String files[] = src.list();
            int filesLength = files.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                String src1 = (new File(src, files[i]).getPath());
                String dst1 = dst.getPath();
                copyFileOrDirectory(src1, dst1);

            }
        } else {
            copyFile(src, dst);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists())
        destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    if (!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    } finally {
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public static void copyDatabase(Context c) {
        String databasePath = c.getDatabasePath("Gsensor.db").getPath();
        File f = new File(databasePath);
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        InputStream myInput = null;
        Log.d("testing", " testing db path " + databasePath);
        Log.d("testing", " testing db exist " + f.exists());

        if (f.exists()) {
            try {

                File directory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/DB_DEBUG");
                if (!directory.exists())
                    directory.mkdir();

                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/" + "hoho.sqlite");
                myInput = new FileInputStream(databasePath);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (myOutput != null) {
                        myOutput.close();
                        myOutput = null;
                    }
                    if (myInput != null) {
                        myInput.close();
                        myInput = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```